# Web Tracker Apache Unomi

Tags: forms, apache-unomi

I'm working on a project that uses the **Apache Unomi**, I had installed all the requirements installation for the Apache Unomi and created a profile and some rules, and all worked well.
But, when I tried to test the web tracker example provided in the Apache Unomi documentation.
[image: Web Tracker]

I got the following error before pressing the submit button

> [UNOMI] XML request error: Unsupported Media Type (415) unomi-tracker.js:16068:29
> onreadystatechange http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:16068

and after the submitting, I got those errors

> XHRPOSThttp://localhost:8181/cxs/context.json
> [HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type 4ms]

> [UNOMI] XML request error: Unsupported Media Type (415) unomi-tracker.js:16068:29
> onreadystatechange http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:16068
> (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
> ajax http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:16053
> loadContext http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:15788
> initialize http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:15622
> initialize http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:4064
> initialize http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:1433
> baseEach http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:595
> each http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:633
> initialize http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:1409
> exports http://localhost:8181/tracker/unomi-tracker.js:5500
> callback http://localhost:8181/tracker/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@acme.com#:84
> load http://localhost:8181/tracker/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@acme.com#:112
> (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
> load http://localhost:8181/tracker/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@acme.com#:110
> (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
>  http://localhost:8181/tracker/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@acme.com#:128
>  http://localhost:8181/tracker/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@acme.com#:143

Because of the errors, the event is not sent to the Apache Unomi.

Comment: Which unomi version are you using?

Comment: I was using Apache Unomi 2.0.0,
I searched for this version and found that this version is unstable.
So, I used Apache Unomi 1.6.0 and the web tracker worked well.